# Как вставить png с прозрачным фоном?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте!

В приложении у `Layout` задан background, сверху положил `ImageView` c png с прозрачным фоном.

В результате получилась прямоугольная картинка с белым фоном.

Как правильно настроить прозрачность png?

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_hause"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: так в чем проблема сделать прозрачным ImageView, или то что он у Вас закрашивается?

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте выставить атрибут `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`